# Moment.js diff of two moments defined by week and weekday gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to calculate the difference between a moment (itemMoment) and now (nowMoment) defined by weekday, hour and minute. If the itemMoment is before nowMoment (diff < 0) I want to add one week and calculate the difference again, but the addition of a week (week: week + 1 in my code )somehow doesn't change the difference and I still get a negative difference.

It's the first time I use the moment.js library so may be I don't get it how to use it correctly. Would be great if an experienced used could help.

```
var now = moment();
  var year = now.year();
  var week = now.week();
  var weekday = now.weekday();
  var hour = now.hour();
  var minute = now.minute();

var itemMoment = moment({
                                day: item.weekday,
                                hour: item.hour,
                                minute: item.minute
                            });
    var nowMoment = moment({
                                day: weekday,
                                hour: hour,
                                minute: minute
                            });

    if (itemMoment.diff(nowMoment) > 0) {
        item.date = moment({
                            year: year, 
                            week: week, 
                            weekday: item.weekday, 
                            hour: item.hour, 
                            minute: item.minute
                        });
        diff = itemMoment.diff(nowMoment);
    }
    else {
        if (week == 51) {
            week = -1;
            year = year + 1
        }
        item.date = moment({
                            year: year, 
                            week: week + 1, 
                            weekday: item.weekday, 
                            hour: item.hour, 
                            minute: item.minute
                        });
        diff = item.date.diff(now);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do comparison using isBefore() or isAfter(). http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

```
if (itemMoment.isBefore(nowMoment)) {
```

Then you can do manipulation like so: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

```
item.date = itemMoment.add('weeks', 1);
```